# What's the formula for calculating Key Efficiency, Key Buffer Used, and Query Cache Hitrate in MySql?

Tags: mysql

Now, I have retrieved some dates from table of 'GLOBAL_STATUS' and 'GLOBAL_VARIABLES' by MySQL DB named information_schema .

I can retrieve

- key_buffer_size
- key_cache_block_size
- query_cache_limit
- Query_cache_size... and so on...

  But, I don't know how to calculate the rate of **Key hitrate**, **Key buffer used**,and   **query cache hitrate**

so, someone can get the formula about those, such as
**`? / ? * 100% = ?`**

Answer (score 11):

For your reference i am trying to explain some concepts also.

**Key hit rate**

There are basically two forms of key hit rate

**1.Key Read Efficiency**

> Key Reads: The number of physical reads of a key block from disk.
>
> Key Read Request: The number of requests to read a key block from the
>   cache.

```
Key Read Efficiency = [1 - (Key_reads/Key_read_requests)]*100
```

> Key Read Efficiency: The ratio of the number of physical reads of a
>   key block from the cache to the number of requests to read a key block
>   from the cache in percentage. The MySQL performance is good if the
>   value of Key Read Efficiency is 90 percent and above. Increasing the
>   size of the cache improves the value of Key Read Efficiency and hence
>   an improved the performance.

**2.Key Write Efficiency**

> Key Writes: The number of physical writes of a key block to disk.
>
> Key Write Request: The number of requests to write a key block to the
>   cache.

```
Key Write Efficiency=(Key_write/Key_write_requests)*100
```

> Key Write Efficiency: The ratio of the number of physical writes of a
>   key block to the cache to the number of requests to write a key block
>   to the cache in percentage. For a good performance of the MySQL
>   server, the value of Key Write Efficiency must be 90 percent and
>   above. If it is found less, then you can increase the size of the
>   cache to improve the performance.

**Key Buffer Used**

Find value of key_buffer_size as `show variables like 'key_buffer_size';`

convert it into MB.

Find the All MyISAM index Size :

> SELECT SUM(INDEX_LENGTH)/(1024*1024) 'Index Size' FROM
>   information_schema.TABLES where ENGINE='MyISAM' AND TABLE_SCHEMA NOT
>   IN('mysql','information_schema');

Find

```
(Index Size)/key_buffer_size(in MB) * 100
```

> if result is (<=100 ) then your all indexes are cached into key_buffer
>
> if result is (>100) then your all indexes are not cached into
>   key_buffer you may gain performance boost by increasing
>   key_buffer_size.

**query cache hitrate**

> Hit rate = Qcache_hits / (Qcache_hits + Com_select) * 100
>
> Insert rate = Qcache_inserts / (Qcache_hits + Com_select) * 100
>
> Prune rate = (Qcache_lowmem_prunes / Qcache_inserts) * 100

Comment: Very nice. You makes me question. Thank you very much, this is my first time to ask a question in English!

Comment: oh great !!!.Hope that answer will help you.

Comment: Why is the key read efficiency "1-" but the key write efficiency is not?

Answer (score 0):

For those using MySQL Administrator, [here is a nice script I found](http://www.jroller.com/dschneller/entry/enhanced_mysql_administrator_graphs), which shows the main interesting values.

Worked perfectly for me (Win7 x64, MySQL 5.1.3 on Debian).

Thanks to the guy who wrote it !

Answer (score 0):

I don't frequent here but the formula in the top answer for Hit Rate is not right. Please see [Optimizing MySQL query_cache_size](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7344/optimizing-mysql-query-cache-size) for the proper formula.

Comment: I appreciate that you don't have the necessary reputation to post comments, but soon you will!

Answer (score 0):

(Now it is 2019.)

I suggest that the question is moot since you should not be using MyISAM. Instead, you should be using InnoDB, which has different metrics.

And the Query Cache has been removed from MySQL 8.0.  And it is not usable in many multi-master setup, including Galera and Group Replication.